# Unable to read LinkedIn content on Linux using Node request module

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, request, node-request

I am using the Node request module for reading site content.  I am not getting the full body content of linkedin.com when I use Node on Linux, but it works fine on Windows & Mac OS X.

I have written the following code:

```
var request = require('request')
request('https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/social-media-why-its-essential-tool-oliver-bussmann', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    } else {
        // always return this response  
        console.log(response.statusCode,body)
    });
```

I am getting a `999` status code and the following HTML content:

> \n\nwindow.onload = function() {\n  // Parse the tracking code from cookies.\n  var trk = "sentinel_org_block";\n  var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");\n  for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {\n    if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {\n trk = cookies[i].substring(8);\n    }\n  }\n\n  // Get the protocol for the redirect url.\n  var protocol = "http:";\n  if (window.location.protocol == "https:") {\n    protocol = "https:";\n  } else {\n    // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.\n    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {\n      if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {\n      window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);\n     return;\n      }\n    }\n  }\n\n  // Get the new domain. For touch.www.linkedin.com or tablet.www.linkedin.com\n  // we strip "touch." and "tablet.". For international domains such as\n  // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com\n  var domain = location.host;\n  if (domain.substr(0, 6) == "touch.") {\n    domain = domain.substr(6);\n  } else if (domain.substr(0, 7) == "tablet.") {\n  domain = domain.substr(7);\n  } else if (domain.charAt(2) == ".") {\n  domain = "www" + domain.substr(2);\n  }\n  \n  window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/uas/login?trk=" + trk + "&session_redirect="
>               +\n      encodeURIComponent(protocol + "//" + domain +\n      window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.search(window.location.host)
>               +\n                                  window.location.host.length));\n}\n\n\n

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is error message? Or what exactly is wrong?

Comment: i did not get content just get all script

Comment: That's not helpful at all, unless you tell us what's wrong we can't help you.

Comment: @FabioAntunes i not get original content like html part & same code run in window that's work fine (Giving all content).

Comment: its giving me statusCode 999

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem when I try to access a LinkedIn profile with a Node.js program, on a Mac OS X machine. Here is the code with the indentation, for a better understanding :

```
window.onload = function() {
     // Parse the tracking code from cookies.
     var trk = "sentinel_org_block";
     var cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
     for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
        if ((cookies[i].indexOf("trkCode=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 8)) {
            trk = cookies[i].substring(8);  
        } 
     }
     // Get the protocol for the redirect url.
     var protocol = "http:";
     if (window.location.protocol == "https:") { 
        protocol = "https:"; 
     } else {
      // If "sl" cookie is set, redirect to https.
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; ++i) {
             if ((cookies[i].indexOf("sl=") == 0) && (cookies[i].length > 3)) {
                 window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
                  return;
            }
        }
    }
    // Get the new domain. For touch.www.linkedin.com or tablet.www.linkedin.com 
    // we strip "touch." and "tablet.". For international domains such as 
    // fr.linkedin.com, we convert it to www.linkedin.com
    var domain = location.host;
    if (domain.substr(0, 6) == "touch.") {
        domain = domain.substr(6);
    } else if (domain.substr(0, 7) == "tablet.") {
        domain = domain.substr(7);
    } else if (domain.charAt(2) == ".") {
        domain = "www" + domain.substr(2);
    }
    window.location.href = "https://" + domain + "/uas/login?trk=" + trk + "&session_redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(protocol + "//" + domain + window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.search(window.location.host) + window.location.host.length));
}
```

It seems that it is a script made to block connections from automated programs, and redirect the user on a login page. It searches for a variable called 'sl' stored inside your cookies. If you got it, the redirection is made to the right webpage. But if you don't, the script does not allow you to see this page and redirects you to the LinkedIn login page.
So this is what I could understand from this code, but unfortunately I have not been able to solve this problem...

**Edit:** I have been able to solve my problem by using PhantomJS to access the page. This way you can modify your user agent, so LinkedIn will not block your connection.
Here is the code I used:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
    var sitepage = null;
    var phInstance = null;

    phantom
        .create()
        .then(function(instance) {
            phInstance = instance;
            return instance.createPage();
        })
        .then(function(page) {
            sitepage = page;
            page.setting('userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36');
            return page.open(this.url);
        })
        .then(function(status) {
            console.log(status)
            return sitepage.property('content');
        })
        .then(function (body) {
            console.log(body);
            sitepage.close();
            phInstance.exit();
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            phInstance.exit();
        });
```